# Can Sandcastle be configured to produce SEO friendly pages and links?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation, seo, sandcastle

By default I see that [Sandcastle](http://blogs.msdn.com/sandcastle/) is generating HTML pages and links named with GUIDs. Can somehow this be changed to generate user/SEO friendly names for the pages? Ie. instead of `f987d4ff-cabc-10af-86cd-620978605d86.htm` I want it create 'namespace.class.method.htm', similar to how the [.Net MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader.aspx) is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Sandcastle Help File Builder, you could try this setting, available in the GUI as "NamingMethod":

```
<NamingMethod>MemberName</NamingMethod>
```

Don't know if it *exactly* fits your needs, but it is an alternative to the GUIDs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

**NamingMethod = MemberName**

Additionally you can research implementing your own naming routine. Check out [this thread for some more information](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=33948)